# XMLA Discover unparse results error (in Mondrian on Windows 7)

Tags: mondrian, xmla

I setup Mondrian and it is working fine but I am unable to make it the XMLA provider.

ie., `http://localhost:8080/mondrian` works fine but `http://localhost:8080/mondrian/xmla.jsp` returns the below error :-

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server.00HSBE02</faultcode>
<faultstring>XMLA Discover unparse results error</faultstring>
<faultactor>Mondrian</faultactor>
<detail>
<XA:error>
<code>00HSBE02</code>
<desc>The Mondrian XML: In DataSources: In DataSource: Expected <ProviderName> but found <Catalogs>
</desc>
</XA:error>
</detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check your mondrian.properties file or your datasources.xml file, and just add the tag:

`<DataSourceName>Provider=Mondrian;DataSource=YourDataSourceName;</DataSourceName>`

That's it. Good luck